# Load Config File Before Library in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, app-config

I am loading the google-api-php-client library (for oauth 2.0 usage) in my codeigniter project. I would like to have a series of configuration values defined in a config file so that they can be used with this library. I am, however, noticing that the configuration info for the library is loaded before the config file that I have defined.

For example, in `autoload.php`, I have set the config autoloads as follows:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('my_config_file');
```

Within `my_config_file.php` I have a series of `define` statements to set the config values:

```
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_NAME','My Application Name');
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID','My App Client ID');
define('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET','My App Client Secret');
```

I would like to use these in the config for the google-api-php-client library:

```
global $apiConfig;
$apiConfig = array(
    'application_name' => GOOGLE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_NAME,
    'oauth2_client_id' => GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    'oauth2_client_secret' => GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET
);
```

After doing this (and some debugging), I've determined that the config file for the library is executed before the autoloaded config file. This is further shown by the errors I get:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant GOOGLE_OAUTH_APPLICATION_NAME ...
Notice: Use of undefined constant GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID ...
Notice: Use of undefined constant GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET ...
```

How do I get it so that these global config constants are defined before the library config is loaded (thus resolving this issue)?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard codeigniter config files?  If you really want to have a dedicated config file for your google api library, I'd include it directly from that library rather than using autoload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to create a separate config file for a library; say `application/config/oauth.php`.

That config file gets loaded in the constructor of your library with `$this->config->load('oauth');`. Of course, you can also just include it in the autoload array.

In your library, you then call the config items thusly:

```
$apiConfig = array(
    'application_name' => $this->config->item('google_oauth_application_name', 'oauth'),
    'oauth2_client_id' => $this->config->item('oauth2_client_id', 'oauth'),
    'oauth2_client_secret' => $this->config->item('oauth2_client_secret', 'oauth')
);
```

Cheers.

Comment: The issue with this is that I want 1 config file for the whole application so that setting up a new instance of it only requires changes to 1 file (we plan on open-sourcing the code and application, so the oauth info will likely change from one instance to another).

Is this a generally bad idea? Or is it feasible to do in a manner that isn't really 'hacky'?

Comment: You can definitely have a single config file, but it should live within the CI scope -- it will make things easier in the long run. Avoid `define`-ing things if you can. If you're publishing the application, leave the sensitive info and create a `config.sample.php` with placeholders.

Comment: So I've decided to go with this solution, but I have a few more questions. 

Because the config values are used so often elsewhere, I want them to be auto-loaded. I can do this just fine in autoload.php. The problem I have, is that I don't want them to be part of the massive CI_Config Object.

I want them to be loaded in the same was as running `$this->config->load('oauth', TRUE)` would load them. That way I can use a hook, and preset a protected controller variable controller with only the values from this config file.

Is this possible without hacking the core files, and if so, how?